# Use property for inner component for Spring component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a components whose members are populated from the YAML file. I have a inner component to this component who also have some members populated from the YAML.

But when I start the app, the members of the inner component are not populated though the instance is created. The main components members are loaded up fine.

Need to know why the members of the Department components are not loaded from the YAML.

**update**

I can see the that inner class is loaded with the members but that is done later during the application load but the `Company` component is used for loading some other components before that. So I need the inner class/component to be initialized immediately after the `Company` component is initialized.

This is how my component is defined

```
@Component
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company")
public class Company {

    @JsonProperty("connectTimeout")
    private Integer connectTimeout;
    @JsonProperty("socketTimeout")
    private Integer socketTimeout;
    @JsonProperty("clientTimeout")
    private Integer clientTimeout;
    @JsonProperty("dept1")
    @Autowired
    private Department library;
    @JsonProperty("dept2")
    @Autowired
    private Department admin;
    @JsonProperty("dept3")
    @Autowired
    private Department transport;
    @JsonProperty("dept4")
    @Autowired
    private Department finance;

    //Getters and Setters

    @Component
    @SuppressWarnings({"PublicInnerClass", "WeakerAccess"})
    public static class Department {

        @JsonProperty("connectTimeout")
        private Integer connectTimeout;
        @JsonProperty("socketTimeout")
        private Integer socketTimeout;
        @JsonProperty("clientTimeout")
        private Integer clientTimeout;

        //Getters and Setters
    }
}
```

The below is my YAML file

```
company:
  connectTimeout: 1000
  socketTimeout: 20000
  clientTimeout: 150
  dept1:
    connectTimeout: 100
    socketTimeout: 100
    clientTimeout: 100
  dept2:
    connectTimeout: 100
    socketTimeout: 100
    clientTimeout: 100
  dept3:
    connectTimeout: 100
    socketTimeout: 100
    clientTimeout: 100
  dept4:
    connectTimeout: 100
    socketTimeout: 100
    clientTimeout: 100
```

Comment: You seem to think that Jackson annotations, used to tell how a class is serialized/deserialized to/from JSON, will be used somehow to map a bean to properties. That won't happen. Here's the documentation for Spring Boot configurations properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties. Read it and follow its instructions carefully.

Comment: As @JBNizet said, the annotation `@JsonProperty` is used for the marshalling/unmarshalling of JSONs. If you want to pass the YAML values to the classes you should use spring `@Value` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have the following property holder dto's `Company` & `Department`;

```
public class Company {

    private Integer connectTimeout;
    private Integer socketTimeout;
    private Integer clientTimeout;
    private Department library;
    private Department admin;
    private Department transport;
    private Department finance;

    public void setDept1(Department dept1) {
        this.library = dept1;
    }

    public void setDept2(Department dept2) {
        this.admin = dept2;
    }

    public void setDept3(Department dept3) {
        this.transport = dept3;
    }

    public void setDept4(Department dept4) {
        this.finance = dept4;
    }

    // other getter/setters

    public static class Department {

        private Integer connectTimeout;
        private Integer socketTimeout;
        private Integer clientTimeout;

        // getter/setters
    }
}
```

& just define a config property containing bean with;

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company")
    public Company company() {
        return new Company();
    }
}
```

Using `@JsonProperty` wouldn't work with such properties, since that annotation only works with de/serialization through Jackson. `@ConfigurationProperties` focuses on basic getter/setters, just adding setters with those names is sufficient, e.g. `setDept1`, `setDept2` etc.

Read more on externalized configuration on Spring Boot, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)